# cudaHostRegister fails with 'invalid argument' error even with page-aligned memory

Tags: cuda

I have allocated page-aligned memory on host using `posix_memalign`. The call to `posix_memalign` does not return any error. However, using this pointer as argument to `cudaHostRegister` gives me an 'invalid argument' error. What could be the issue?

- CUDA API version: 4.0
- gcc version: 4.4.5
- GPU compute capability: 2.0

The memory allocation is done in the application code, and a pointer is passed to a library routine.

Application code snippet:

```
if(posix_memalign((void **)&h_A, getpagesize(), n * n * sizeof(float))) {
  printf("Error allocating aligned memory for A\n");
  return 1;
}
```

Shared library code snippet:

```
if((ret = cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost)) != cudaSuccess) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device flag: %s\n", 
          cudaGetErrorString(ret));
  return NULL;
}

if((ret = cudaHostRegister(h_A, n2 * sizeof(float), 
                          cudaHostRegisterMapped)) != cudaSuccess) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error registering page-locked memory for A: %s\n", 
          cudaGetErrorString(ret));
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to cuda 5 to see if the issue has been addressed.  What happens if you do an ordinary `malloc()` instead of `posix_memalign()`, are you then able to successfully register the memory?

Comment: Some code illustrating the problem would be very useful-

Comment: Thank you for the responses.
@RobertCrovella: Initially I had tried using `malloc()` but that gave an 'invalid argument' error. That's when I read about the possible problems with unaligned memory, and tried using `posix_memalign()`. Upgrading to CUDA 5 is not an option for me now, as this is a shared server I am using.
@talonmies: I have posted the code as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce this. If I take the code snippets you supplied and make them into a minimal executable:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int n2 = 100 * 100;
    float *h_A;
    cudaError_t ret;

    if(posix_memalign((void **)&h_A, getpagesize(), n2 * sizeof(float))) {
        printf("Error allocating aligned memory for A\n");
        return -1;
    }


    if((ret = cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost)) != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device flag: %s\n", 
                cudaGetErrorString(ret));
        return -1;
    }

    if((ret = cudaHostRegister(h_A, n2 * sizeof(float), 
                    cudaHostRegisterMapped)) != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error registering page-locked memory for A: %s\n", 
                cudaGetErrorString(ret));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it compiles and runs without error under both CUDA 4.2 and CUDA 5.0 on a 64 bit linux host with the 304.54 driver. I would, therefore, conclude that either you have a broken CUDA installation or your code has a problem somewhere you haven't shown us.

Perhaps you can compile and run this code exactly as I posted and see what happens. If it works, it might help narrow down what it is that might be going wrong here.

Comment: Just as another data point, I also ran talonmies code  (I had to `#include <stdio.h>` ) on cuda 4.1 with 285.05.33 driver and it ran without error.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Interestingly, I didn't get an error for the lack of `stdio.h` (this was Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6), which is a bit odd. I have edited the code accordingly